# Given an integral of undefined function, evaluate an integral of a modified function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The question is:

If $$\int_3^9f(x) dx = 7$$ 
evaluate 
$$\int_3^9 2f(x)+1 dx$$

I know that you can factor the 2 outside of the integral. But, then I am still left with a '+ 1' inside the integral that when I take the integral of becomes $x$. So then would I proceed to stating this: 
$$=2\int_3^9 f(x) +1 dx$$
$$=2\int_3^9 f(x)dx +\int_3^91 dx$$
$$= 2\left((7)+\left[x\right]_3^9\right)$$
$$= 2(7+(9-3))$$
$$=26$$

Is this right because the answer in my book says 20, which leads me to believe that they did not multiply the 2 to everything but only to the 7.

$$= 2(7)+\left[x\right]_3^9$$
$$=2(7) + 6$$
$$= 14 +6$$
$$=20$$

Is my interpretation of the textbook's answer correct? If so, if I factor the 2 out of the integral, why does it only apply to the 7? If not, then what am I doing wrong in my first solution?

Comment: $2$ multiplies only $f(x)$, not also $+1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your textbook is right, if you apply the 2 to the 1 in the last step you should also have applied it to the 1 at factoring it out, thus having 1/2 in the second integral. This should also lead to your textbook's answer.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_3^9 2\ f(x) + 1\ \text{d}x = 2\int_3^9 f(x)\ \text{d}x + \int_3^9 1\ \text{d}x$$

Since you already know what the $f(x)$ integral is, you just have to evaluate the other trivial one.

$$ = 2\cdot 7 + x\bigg|_3^9 = 14 + (9 - 3) = 20$$

The $2$ factor does multiply $f(x)$ only.

You have

$$2\ f(x) + 1$$

Not

$$2\left(f(x) + 1\right)$$

Comment: Mais oui! I can't seem to get that across!

Answer (score 0):

Look at your algebra; you have extended the parenthesis too far.  The factor of $2$ does not extend to the second integral.

Comment: But if I wrote $2\int_3^9 1+ f(x)dx$ and then split it, would the 2 apply to the 1?

Comment: That is now what you have written.